# CFSAVECONTENT in CFSCRIPT

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am good fan of cfsavecontent due to we can convert long text to variable (Event I can dump in it). But recently more started working with CFSCRIPT and can't figure out how to use it inside cfscript tag.

Is there any way to write cfsavecontent inside cfscript. As per my knowledge there is no such function or class available and sure it is pretty hard to implement as well.

Appreciate any feedback.

Thanks
Pritesh

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using CF9 and railo you can use savecontent {}
see more info here:

http://www.isummation.com/blog/cfsavecontent-in-cf9-cfscript/

It's not quite the same as you need to use writeoutput to output the items. This can also done by appending output to a variable.

Comment: Just to add to this, there's a list of script tag-equivalents in the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html.  This is perhaps the best place to look when wondering "is [some tag]'s functionality supported in CFScript".

Comment: Thanks Dawesi, I was looking to cf8 documentation :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the answer from the linked page from Dawesis answer (CF9):

```
savecontent variable="myVariable" { WriteOutput("Hello World"); }
```